# How to prove that $I+A^{T}A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

> Let $A$ be any $m\times n$ matrix and $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity.
>   Prove that $I+A^{T}A$ is invertible.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 4):

The matrix $I+A^TA$ is invertible because it is positive definite: if $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is nonzero, then
$$
v^T(I+A^TA)v=v^Tv+v^TA^TAv=|v|^2+|Av|^2\geq |v|^2>0.
$$
In particular, all the eigenvalues are positive and their product must too be positive (i.e. nonzero).